# Rails partial rendering twice on changing the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I m new to RoR and i recently figured out that if I change the part of URL from the address bar it is just rendering the partial twice below I m illustrating the same.
So my url is **localhost:3000/admin/exp_app/10** so if i refresh this page it gets rendered one time but if i change the url to **localhost:3000/admin/exp_app/11** the same request gets twice to controller and it is rendering the partial two times .
Can someone help me?

Below i m attaching the part of code.
exp_controller.rb

```
 def show
      authorize! :sales, current_user

      @filter = params[:filter] || 'all'
      @filter_by = params[:filter_by] || 'all'
      @analytics_filter = params[:analytics_filter] || 'all'
      @uw = params[:uw_id]
      @entity = params[:entity]
      @leo_no_brc = params[:leo_no_brc].present?
      @exporter_application = User.exp_leads_applications.find(params[:id]) rescue nil

      user = User.find(params[:id]) if @exporter_application.nil? || can?(:mexico_sales, current_user)
      @total_ltm = @exporter_application.shipment_volume_last_year(nil, false).to_i
      @exp_clients = @exporter_application.clients
      @exp_applications_clients = @exp_clients.where(status: Client::CLIENT_STATUS_ORDER).group_by(&:status)
      @exp_task_instances = @exporter_application.task_instances.where(client_id: nil)
       @exporter_application = User.exp_leads_applications.includes(:iec, :contacts,
                                                                   interactions: [:replies],
                                                                   task_instances: { interactions: [:replies] },
                                                                   application: { exporter_user: [:iec] })
      end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% if params[:_tpl] %>

<div class="admin-section tabpanel row">
  <%= render partial: params[:_tpl], locals: { instance: @exporter_application } %>
</div>

<% else %>

<%= render 'admin/header' %>

<%= render partial: 'admin/exporter_applications/show' %>

<%= render 'admin/footer' %>

<% end %>
```

It is guranteed that this url is not called in partial again **admin/exporter_applications/show** 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the response in your browser's console first. Does it look ok, or is it doubled?

Comment: Double, by using rack-mini-profiler i can see that

Comment: Ok, and it's just repeated response from `admin/exp_app/11`?

Comment: Yes, so how can i prevent it?

Comment: IDK yet, I'd try to simplify things. Remove all the code from your view, leave only single word e.g. "hello" and check if you have duplication.